# How to classify both sentiment and genres from movie reviews using CNN Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science

I am trying to classify sentiment on movie review and predict the genres of that movie based on the review itself. Now Sentiment is a Binary Classification problem where as Genres can be Multi-Label Classification problem.

Another example to clarify the problem is classifying Sentiment of a sentence and also predicting whether the tone of the sentence is happy, sarcastic, sad, pitiful, angry or fearful.

More to that is, I want to perform this classification using Tensorflow CNN. My problem is in structuring the y_label and training the data such that the output helps me retrieve Sentiment as well as the genres.
Eg Data Y Label: [[0,1],[0,1,0,1,0]] for sentiment as Negative and mood as sarcastic and angry

How do you suggest I tackle this?

Comment: You can treat this as a `multi-label` problem, and append the `sentiment` and the `tone` labels together.

Comment: Is that optimal method? If the first category(here,sentiment) and second category (eg areas of literature eg Science, Law, Sociology, as Multi-Class Classification Problem) have no semantic relation will the network still be as effective?

Comment: why should the outputs have any relation with each other?. The input-output should have the semantic relationship not between outputs.

Comment: @vijaym So, just to clarify; I should change the y_label to [0,1,0,1,0,1,0] and train the CNN module with sigmoid function to obtain the logits right?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically at the final layer of the CNN as you've resized the CNN output to a form of 1x1xN, add two Feed-Forward Neural Networks. So if you have a simple classification problem you feed the output of the CNN into a Feed-Forward Neural Network, now in this case you'll have two of these networks.  So in order to accomplish this basically you'll have the following:

- CNN output ---feed---> Classifier#1
- CNN output ---feed---> Classifier#2

Thus you'll have to separate classifications BUT you'll still have to backpropagate them so it will look something like this:

```
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction1, labels_1))
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction2, labels_2))

loss = loss1 + loss2
```

So you'll "minimize" the `loss` with an optimizer.

Comment: Can you add code portion on how to add two feed forward networks on logits? How is it different from using Multi class as vijay suggested?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it helps. Feel free to ask any further questions.