# Tensorflow : Cross Entropy for Multi labels classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm using a neural network for classification of a set of objects into n-classes. Each object can belong to multiple classes at the same time (multi-class, multi-label).

For example :

```
Input is ['a','b','c']  and labels are  [1,0,0,1,1,1]  # where 1 means it is in class and 0 means it's not in class  it's multi labels classification
```

I search and found people are suggesting you should use sigmoid instead of softmax in Multi-label problems.

some references are :

[Sentiment and genres classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004514/how-to-classify-both-sentiment-and-genres-from-movie-reviews-using-cnn-tensorflo/45005490?noredirect=1#comment87586644_45005490)

[reddit group suggestion on multi label classification](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/5g3got/how_can_i_use_tensorflow_image_classifier_to_do/)

[Excellent blog on explaining the theory of multi label classification](https://nickcdryan.com/2017/01/23/multi-label-classification-a-guided-tour/)

[another good tutorial on multi label](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-multi-class-multi-label-classification-for-news-categories/)

[Stack exchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207794/what-loss-function-for-multi-class-multi-label-classification-tasks-in-neural-n)

Now after reading those things , I got it that i should go for sigmoid butI have few confusions :

so for single classification what i was doing :

After model (hiddenlayers with lstm )  i was building fully connected layer :

```
    #weights
    Wo = tf.get_variable('Wo', 
                    shape=[hdim*2, num_labels], 
                    dtype=tf.float32, 
                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))


   #bias
   bo = tf.get_variable('bo', 
                    shape=[num_labels,], 
                    dtype=tf.float32, 
                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))


  #logits
  logits = tf.matmul(tf.concat([fsf.c, fsb.c], axis=-1), Wo) + bo


   #probability 
   probs  = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

   #taking max probability
   preds  = tf.argmax(probs, axis=-1)


   # Cross Entropy
   ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)

   #loss
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce)

   # Accuracy
   accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(
                            tf.cast(
                                tf.equal(tf.cast(preds, tf.int32), labels),
                                tf.float32
                                )
  #training                         )
  trainop = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

But In multi-labels how should i take inputs :

so what i tried :

```
   #weights
    Wo = tf.get_variable('Wo', 
                    shape=[hdim*2, num_labels], 
                    dtype=tf.float32, 
                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))


   #bias
   bo = tf.get_variable('bo', 
                    shape=[num_labels,], 
                    dtype=tf.float32, 
                    initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))


  #logits
  logits = tf.matmul(tf.concat([fsf.c, fsb.c], axis=-1), Wo) + bo


   #probability 
   probs  = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)

   #taking max probability
   preds  = tf.round(probs)




   # Cross Entropy
   ce = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)

   #loss
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(ce)

   # Accuracy
   accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(
                            tf.cast(
                                tf.equal(tf.cast(preds, tf.int32), labels),
                                tf.float32
                                )
  #training                         )
  trainop = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

Is this right approach , AM i doing right or need correction somewhere ?

If i  passing to tf.nn.sigmoid should i need to pass to  tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits or not ??

Thanks You .

Comment: This seems fine, what was the question about the sigmoid?. You are doing it right in the code above.